# Changing boot priority - Ubuntu fresh install from windows 10 -

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, boot, priority

On my old laptop, a Samsung NP915S3G-K03UK <sup>[[1](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/NP915S3G-K01UK),[2](https://us.hardware.info/product/194506/samsung-np915s3g-k03uk/specifications)]</sup>, I was changing the OS from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

**What I have done**

- Booted the software launcher from a USB
- Installed and restarted the laptop.

**Situation**
Now I can't see the option to change the boot priority from USB to the installed OS.
There are no other options available other than USB.

When I remove the USB then the system, and I reboot, I get the message:

> All boot options are tried. Press  key to recover with factory image using 
>   Recovery or any other keys for next boot loop iteration.

Any suggestions/ handy commands to make the option visible?

Comment: The boot priority only shows the USB drive not the linux installation

Comment: Your HDD is shown in bios?